# How to print constraint evaluation in OPL for a specific instance

Tags: cplex, constraint-programming, opl, cp-optimizer

I have a simple question but I can't find how to tackle it. For instance, consider the following .mod file from a scheduling problem in OPL using the CP Optimizer solver.

```
using CP;
    
    int nbJobs = ...;
    int nbMchs = ...;
    
    range Jobs = 0..nbJobs-1;
    range Mchs = 0..nbMchs-1; 
    
    int OpDurations[j in Jobs][m in Mchs] = ...;
    
    dvar interval itvs[j in Jobs][m in Mchs] size OpDurations[j][m];
    dvar sequence mchs[m in Mchs] in all(j in Jobs) itvs[j][m];
    
    execute {
            cp.param.FailLimit = 10000;
    }
    
    minimize max(j in Jobs) endOf(itvs[j][nbMchs-1]);
    subject to {
      forall (m in Mchs)
        noOverlap(mchs[m]);
      forall (j in Jobs, o in 0..nbMchs-2)
        endBeforeStart(itvs[j][o], itvs[j][o+1]);
    }
```

I just want to print how a constraint set is evaluated for a particular instance (.dat file). For instance, let's say we want to print how the constraint: forall (m in Mchs)          noOverlap(mchs[m]); is evaluated for different values of m.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that through scripting if you rely on " Opl. "

```
using CP;

int n=10;
int d[i in 1..n]=i;

dvar interval A[i in 1..n] size d[i];
dvar interval B[i in 1..n] in 1..10 size 3 ;
dvar sequence p in A ; 

subject to {
  noOverlap(p);
  startOf(B[1])==2;
};

execute
{
  writeln(Opl.noOverlap(A));
  writeln(Opl.noOverlap(B));
}
```

gives

```
1
0
```